# Why Watir Chrome Headless 'not clickable at point (x,y)' when all fine in with browser mode?

Tags: watir, google-chrome-headless

I have a scraping script written in Ruby which uses Selenium, Watir and ChromeDriver, all is working just fine with a Chrome browser window, but trying to run in headless mode just hits;

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Element <input id="desired_element" type="checkbox" name="desired_element" checked="checked"> is not clickable at point (660, 594). Other element would receive the click: <html lang="en">...</html>
```

I'm using Watir 6.8 and latest Chromedriver 2.33.

Any ideas whats n=behind the different behavior of the page when in headless vs non headless, and how I can deal with this?

Comment: it would be helpful if you were to include the actual code that is failing to execute, as well as a sample of the HTML which the code interacts with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is telling you what the problem is when it says "Other element would receive the click:"

This means some other element on the screen is covering the checkbox you are trying to interact with.  Likely this is caused by whatever the default browser size in headless mode being different than the default size of your browser when it is run non-headless, resulting in a different arrangement of elements

We can verify if this is the case by asking the size of the window in both headless and normal modes and seeing if the resulting values are the same.

```
size = browser.window.size
puts "The browser window is #{size.width} wide by #{size.height} high"
```

There are a few potential ways to solve this:

1. Specify or alter the browser 'window' size. for example
   `browser.window.resize_to 1024, 768`

   I prefer this, and normally have a command such as that to set the
   browser size right after it is initialized.  Set either to the
   minimum supported size for your site, or the minimum recommended
   size
2. Use another means to 'click' on the checkbox, such as sending a space at it 
   `@browser.checkbox(name: "desired_element").send_keys " "`

   I do not prefer this as it doesn't really solve the source of the problem and you may experience other similar issues interacting with other elements on the site as your script progresses.

Comment: Thanks Chuck, matching the headless window size to the window size 'with head' (correct term?!) worked perfectly here. Though I understood that the error message was telling me that another element was in the expected location of the desired element, I couldn't quite see why, and how to solve the problem. Thanks for helping me out of that hole . I don't quite understand how Watir 'logs' the location of elements, does it do this on page load, therefore if any javascript elements change the dom it could cause problems as elements change position from their first on load locations?

Comment: I don't believe watir 'logs' locations, I think it gets them from the DOM (technically at that point it's webdriver doing the work).  What happened here is a not uncommon issue with "reactive" sites that respond to browser width  and reformat the page to fit and look nice.  Often there is a minimum width that they support, and if the browser is under that width you end up with a lot of objects overlapping because it just can't fit them all neatly on the page.

Comment: If you want to see what was happening under headless, use the commands I put above to get the default size of the headless browser.  Then startup a non headless session under IRB and use the second command to set that window to the same size the headless browser was using.  Then you can see how the page is being arranged, and what elements might be overlapping, when the browser is that size.

Answer (score -3):

The reason for this kind of error is that web page doesn't load well enough to locate the element. As you have mentioned that the tests previously passed when you had headless true such issues might be because of .click() , please try replacing .click with .send_keys

```
.send_keys(selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.SPACE)
```

When you use .send_keys() you might hit one more issue if it is failing to find elements, for solving this you will have to find the elements

```
elements = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html")
elements.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The element is being found it seems, otherwise it would give an element not found error surely? Instead it gives an `element not clickable at point (x,y)` error, which suggests that the element has moved from the location that it originally located it at.

For example, previous elements on the page were conditional which popped other elements into the page changing the location of the 'desired_element' from the position on first load.

It seems to me that this might be what's happening, but it has no problem with this same behaviour in 'head' mode.

Comment: Neither locating the element first nor send_keys helps here. FYI the actual code I;m trying to execute is; `@browser.checkbox(name: "desired_element").clear`

Comment: downvoted because user clearly indicated they were using Watir, but answer is phrased using entirely Selenium API not the Watir API